# Is the fact that there are qualia something internal or external?

Tags: consciousness, self, qualia

I'm struggling to digest the SEP article on [qualia](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qualia/).

Is anyone saying that ***there being*** qualia is something about the world which exists independent of conscious awareness (knowledge and perception)?

What would you call this existing thing, of there being qualia?

It seems easy to suggest that I am the bundle of qualia I currently have. Does it *make sense*  (I'm not suggesting it) to say that, similarly, *I am* (outside myself and) there being qualia?

Comment: Property dualists (Nigel, Chalmers) are traditionally saying that qualia are irreducibly mental what-it-is-likes. But your phrasing suggests that you are asking if these first person what-it-is-likes can be reduced to third person "independents of conscious awareness". That would kind of defeat the purpose. Property dualism involves giving up the physicalist identification of objectively existent with mind independent in the strong sense of "independent", and chimeric notions like "bundle of qualia". But qualia's existence and nature are still not subject to mind's whim, for example.

Comment: ok @Conifold i didn't understand [this](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qualia/#Repqualia) part i think: "This is not to say that experiences do not have qualia. The point is that qualia are not qualities of experiences. This claim, which will be developed further in the next section, is controversial... qualities represented by experiences (qualities that, in the perceptual case, if they belong to anything, belong to external things), a natural representational proposal is that qualia are really representational contents of experiences into which the represented qualities enter

Comment: This is the distinction between the representational and phenomenal interpretations of knowledge that qualia provide, which often comes up in the discussions of [Mary the Color Scientist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_argument#Acquaintance_hypothesis) scenario. It is mostly a reflection of the general arguments in semantics about the adequacy of representational content to explicating knowledge, dualists like Jackson profess something like direct (non-representational) realism about qualia.